# UI bootstrap : align vertically datetimepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am having troubles with aligning my form components.
As you can see, the datetime picker is not align with cooptation input
[image]

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="field_nom">Nom</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nom" id="field_nom" ng-model="vm.consultant.nom" required />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="col-md-5 control-label" for="field_dateEnregistrement">Date Enregistrement</label>
    <div class="col-md-5 input-group">
      <input id="field_dateEnregistrement" type="text" class="form-control" name="dateEnregistrement" uib-datepicker-popup="{{dateformat}}" ng-model="vm.consultant.dateEnregistrement" is-open="vm.datePickerOpenStatus.dateEnregistrement" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.openCalendar('dateEnregistrement')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                    </span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="field_candidat">Candidat</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="candidat" id="field_candidat" ng-model="vm.consultant.candidat" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="col-md-5 control-label" for="field_cooptation">Cooptation</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cooptation" id="field_cooptation" ng-model="vm.consultant.cooptation" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZYLQAtRlWqkwh53Pm7XK?p=preview

How can I vertically align these components?

**[update]**
Solved :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                    <label class="col-md-5 control-label" for="field_dateEnregistrement">Date Enregistrement</label>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="input-group"> 
                            <input id="field_dateEnregistrement" type="text" class="form-control" name="dateEnregistrement" uib-datepicker-popup="{{dateformat}}" ng-model="vm.consultant.dateEnregistrement" is-open="vm.datePickerOpenStatus.dateEnregistrement"/>
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.openCalendar('dateEnregistrement')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the margin on the id of the element in your CSS file
(I also added the width to make it as wide as the below form) you might want to remove it

```
#field_dateEnregistrement { 
margin-left:14px;
width:211px;
}
```